# What i Mentioned as Return Type

Tags: c#, linq

This is my table Columns

```
 public partial class Dept_Emp
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string F_Name { get; set; }
        public string L_Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string DeprtmentName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Sal { get; set; }
    }
```

When i try to convert above table in to Liq why i'm getting Error as

CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'
 to 'System.Tuple'

```
Public IEnumarable<Dept_Emp> GetEmp(){
    var x = (from de in db.Dept_Emp
                         group de by de.DeprtmentName into g
                         select new
                         {
                             DeprtmentName = g.Key,
                             TotalSalary = g.Sum(x => x.Sal)
                         });
//Here wat I pass
}
```

Comment: Your code contains no lists and no tuples anywhere in it, so clearly this isn't (all of) the code causing the problem.

Comment: @Sevy Could u mention the Code Please

Comment: You asked this question a few hours ago. Still: the code snippet you show works (except for the double `x` declaration). Please show the code that causes the error. It is definitly not the code you posted.

Comment: But srtill I face the Save Problem please Give me any hint How can i solve

Comment: @Servy means the code you've included in your question doesn't obviously show a problem, because there's no reason why the query you posted would make use of List<> or Tuple, so you probably need to include more of your code so people understand your underlying problem. Ideally you should run your code through a debugger and find the line of code where your program crashes, and include the relevant code leading up to that line.

Comment: Ok, now we can see you are trying to return an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type, this is not possible. Note that your `select` returns an enumeration of the anonymous type containing `DepartmentName` and `Salary`, this is not a `Dept_Emp`. Anonymous types cannot be used in return types. You'll need to create an own type.

Comment: Your view has a model of a Tuple type, you need to make it IEnumberable or List if you want your code go forward. Why do you need Tuple?

Comment: soo wil u please Help me how can i write an Easyest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to use *anonymous* types in return types. So you'll need to create an explicit type for the resulting value:

```
// type to hold the result
public class SalariesPerDepartment
{
     public string DepartmentName { get;set; }
     public decimal? TotalSalary { get; set; }
}

                     // use type here
public IEnumarable<SalariesPerDepartment> GetEmp()
{
    return (from de in db.Dept_Emp
             group de by de.DeprtmentName into g
             select new SalariesPerDepartment // instantiate that type
             {
                 DeprtmentName = g.Key,
                 TotalSalary = g.Sum(x => x.Sal)
             });
}
```

Comment: Thank u Soo Much Mr @Rene Vogt

Comment: Love u Rene Love u soo much